# IllegalArgumentException: with Firebase - Convert an anonymous account to a permanent account

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Before I start with my problem, please forgive me my bad English: I'm from Germany and I've English for a long time not used.

I've developed a simple community app with Firebase and it works well. But on some devices the app crashes at this point:

(PasswordDialog.java:163)
AuthCredential authCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential("user@example.com", "password_generated_from_mysql_database");

With this message:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
......
......PasswordDialog.setFirebaseLinkAndDismiss (PasswordDialog.java:163)
......

At first the user enters his data. After that I generate the "getUid" with "firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously" to save this in a MySQL database. please look hier:

```
private void signInFirebaseAnonymously() {
    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    userDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userDatabase").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                    putFirebaseUid = currentUser.getUid();
                    //Log.e(TAG, "uID vorhanden:    currentUser:" + putFirebaseUid);
                    sharedEditor.putString("fbAuthID", currentUser.getUid());
                    sharedEditor.apply();
                    createProfil(putFirebaseUid);
                } 
            }
        });
    } else {
        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        putFirebaseUid = currentUser.getUid();

        sharedEditor.putString("fbAuthID", firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        sharedEditor.apply();
        createProfil(putFirebaseUid);
    }
}
```

If that successful starts a new intent with a password dialog, look her:

```
                    passwordDialog.show();
                    passwordDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                            if(LOGIN_S)
                            {
                                Intent startStart = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Start.class);
                                startActivity(startStart);
                                finish();
                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), R.string.errorcode21, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SP, 0);
                                sharedEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                sharedEditor.clear();   //Clear
                                sharedEditor.apply();
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    passwordDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    passwordDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

in there is sent the password to the MySQL database and comes encrypted back. finally start the convert an anonymous account to a permanent account and crashed in about 30% of all cases. Please look hier:

```
private void setPasswordAndCreateFirebaseAccout(final String userID, final String password){

    AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("id", ""+sharedPreferences.getInt("currentUserID",0))
                    .add("password", password)
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/setPass.php")
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();

            try {
                okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

                if(jsonObject.getString("status").equals("success"))
                {
                    LogState = true;
                    setThisMail = jsonObject.getString("e");
                    setThisPass = jsonObject.getString("p");

                } else {
                    LogState = false;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //Convert an anonymous account to a permanent account
            setFirebaseLinkAndDismiss(setThisMail, setThisPass);
        }

    };
    task.execute();
}
private void setFirebaseLinkAndDismiss(final String fbMail, final String fbPass)
{
   /*here crashes the app: error line PasswordDialog.java:163 */
   AuthCredential authCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(fbMail, fbPass);


    firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(authCredential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        currentUser = task.getResult().getUser();

                        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(fbMail, fbPass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    sharedEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                    sharedEditor.putBoolean("currentUserPasswort", true);
                                    sharedEditor.apply();

                                    LOGIN_S = true;
                                    dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    LOGIN_S = false;
                                    dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        LOGIN_S = false;
                        dismiss();
                    }
                }
    });
}
```

I hope you understand my problem. What can I do?
sincerely regards

Answer (score 0):

In the `AsyncTask` contained in `setPasswordAndCreateFirebaseAccout()`, you set `LogState` to false when the network request fails.  When that happens, it appears that `setThisEmail` and `setThisPass` are undefined, perhaps null (the posted code does not show what value they have in this case).  In `onPostExecute()`, there is no test of `LogState` before the call to  `setFirebaseLinkAndDismiss()`, so it is called when the network request has failed and the email and password are not valid.  I suspect this is the cause of the exception.

To debug this issue, add a log statement at the beginning of `setFirebaseLinkAndDismiss()` that outputs the values of `fbMail` and `fbPass`.  For safety, you should also add checks that they are valid values, e.g. are not null, have the required format (email: xxxx@yyyy.zzz) and length.  Also, since you have encrypted them, check that they do not contain invalid characters.

Comment: Good morning Bob,
that sounds logical. I will try to realize your tip.

many thanks